# last-value in sqoop( incremental import)

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, sqoop

```
sqoop import --connect \\
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ydb --table yloc --username root -P --check-column rank --incremental append --last-value
```

We don't know the last value of the previous table. How can I write the query?

Comment: you need to create a sqoop job so that sqoop metastore will remember the last value..

Comment: OR u can also create a table to persist the last value

Answer (score 0):

You can try to 2 approaches to solve this.

1. Query into table and get maximum value of last-value column.
2. Create a job in sqoop and set the column as incremental one and moving forward, your job will run on incremental basis

Answer (score 0):

- Go to your pwd
- cd **.sqoop**
- open file **metastore.db.script** using vi or
  your fav editor.
- search for **incremental.last.value**

It should be something like

```
INSERT INTO SQOOP_SESSIONS VALUES('incimpjob','incremental.last.value','2018-09-11 19:20:52.0','SqoopOptions')
```

Note: I am assuming that you have created a Sqoop Job. The 'incimpjob' is the name of my sqoop job.